# HOWTO: Visual Studio 2010 MVC3 Project on Win7 x64 Using Oracle ODP.NET 11.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, oracle, odp.net

I have a new development machine Windows 7 x64 and am writing an MVC3 application that targets an Oracle database.  I have tried everything that I know of to get it running with no success.

Previously, I was developing on a Win7 x32 box and could debug fine locally, but was unable to deploy and run it on a  Win2008 x64 Server despite having ODP.Net and 11g Client installed.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format"

On my new x64 machine, I can build the project but when i try to run it in via the IDE I get:

> "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

I am at a complete loss.

**Does anyone have a similar setup that could share detailed instructions of what to install where and how to to reference Oracle.DataAccess in such a way that I can debug in the IDE on my x64 box, and also deploy to x64 server?**

It should not have to be this difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.  Here is what I did step-by-step:

1. On my **Win7 x64 development machine** I removed all Oracle products in an attempt to start from scratch (including manually deleting registry keys and files/folders)
2. I installed *"Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64) "*  ON **BOTH** the dev machine and production IIS server

   - I selected the RUNTIME option for the installation
   - During my first attempt the installation complained of not enough room in the PATH 
     environment variable so I had to cancel the install, remove some path values (which a replaced after the install completed
   - I installed to C:\oracle was my base path and client_x64 was my HOME so it installed to C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_x64
3. I then installed *"64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) for Windows x64"* on **BOTH** the dev and production mahcines.

   > install.bat odp.net4 c:\oracle\odac11.2.x64 odac112x64

   - The above statement creates a new home named odac112x64
4. At this point I built a simple console app using the following setup

   - Added reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll located in C:\oracle\odac11.2.x64\odp.net\bin\4
   - Set CopyLocal = FALSE for the Oracle.DataAccess reference
   - Set the application to build for "ANY PROCESSOR"
   - The app connected to my oracle database and returned records on both machines
5. I then created a sample MVC website project with the same connection code as the console app.
6. When I ran it locally in the IDE it threw an error:

   > "Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess,
   >   Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
   >   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

   - I believe this is because the IDE is 32bit and could not load a 64bit  Oracle.DataAccess
7. I published that exact code to the production server and it ran successfully

   - At this point my only problem is getting it to run locally for development purposes
8. I installed "ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) with Xcopy Deployment" which is the x32 version of ODP.NET

   > install.bat odp.net4 c:\oracle\odac11.2.x32 odac112x32
9. When I re-ran the MVC website project locally it worked as expected!

***UPDATED FOLLOW-UP INFORMATION #1:***
After getting this to work I attempted to apply the same steps to another server and it failed.  The problem was that "Allow 32-bit Applications" was set to TRUE in the application pool.  DISABLING 32-bit apps (only allowing 64bit) resolved the problem on the new machine.

***UPDATED FOLLOW-UP INFORMATION #2:***
The ODAC installation on the new machine failed to place the installation and bin directory in the environment path (I hate Oracle).  Once that was added, all was running as desired.

Comment: Interesting that the x32 version was what ended up working best on your x64 Dev Machine with VS. That's a similar experience to the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I do have this running on Windows 7x64 with the Oracle 11g R2 client that comes with the ODAC installation here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Make sure you have the x64 version installed locally, and you may have to do the uninstall-reboot-reinstall-reboot tango. I also had weird problems getting it to see TNSNAMES entries and had to go with EZCONNECT strings, but that's not your problem.

In fact, I've also gotten it working on x64 using the 32 bit EF beta and it works fine:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html

Although I don't think the EF implementatinon is 100% ready for prime time yet (we ended up using the DevArt driver instead because it had more reliable support for computed fields - we never did get Computed or Identity Timestamps working in ODP.NET EF Beta, although oddly Primary Key NUMBER fields populated by triggers did work.)

I didn't have to do anything special, and I didn't have to do anything special on the server side either (with both 10g and 11gR2).

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with ODP.NET for quite some time, so I am running from memory of issues I had when I last used it.

The ODP.NET bits have to be installed on the server (or at least deployed, although I am not sure how that is accomplished off hand). The actual client in ODP.NET is the same Java libraries used for Oracle access. If installed, then you have some type of configuration error or permissions issue with using the underlying Java libraries.

I am not sure what the IDE message is about, however.